# Accessing IB/TWS API from PowerShell

Tags: tws

I am attempting to access the TWS from Powershell. (Reasoning: want to have small scripts for automating some trading steps.)

However, I simply can't manage to "translate" the C# based documentation into the required PowerShell code. Can anyone reference me somewhere to a small example on PowerShell just to complete the connect step. At least so that I can see how to get the first classes loaded.

I have managed to load the DLL and create an instance of the DefaultEWrapper class. Question: is this the right starting point. But now I fail to get the ClientSocket created.

```
$twsLib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\TWS API\source\CSharpClient\activex\bin\Release\TWSLib.dll")

$tws = New-Object -TypeName IBApi.DefaultEWrapper
```

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0):

```
using module 'C:\IBTrader\CSharpAPI.dll'
[IBApi.DefaultEWrapper]$wrap = New-Object IBApi.DefaultEWrapper
[IBApi.EReaderMonitorSignal]$signal = new-object IBApi.EReaderMonitorSignal
$clientSocket = New-Object IBApi.EClientSocket($wrap, $signal)
$clientSocket.eConnect("localhost",7497,0)
$clientSocket.IsConnected()
```

Been working on this for a couple of hours and have a successful connection.

Now to try do something with it!